# Unir y - how i Put marker in object 3D (.obj) and get the touch listener of it

Tags: unity-game-engine, listener, marker, vuforia

Ji, im new in unity, im doing an app that is a body of a person, then you can tap/hit on you’re mobile for Example the head and the app changes the to another scene.

So what i wanna do is put like kind of buttons in some parts of the body and when the users click it, changes the scene, the proble is that if i put static buttons, if you zoom in/out or rotate the object, the buttons are not gonna move, so how can i attach/put this buttons or listeners to the object?

Pd. I searched and i saw that you can put like some parts with other color and detect the color but idk if this is the best solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Way1:**
You can put a `Collider` in each individual part of the body, like head leg etc.
Then, add script to each of the parts with `OnMouseDown`function in it. This will detect the click/tap on the colliders.
More about `OnMouseDown`here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnMouseDown.html 
**Way2:** You can `Raycast`on mouse click or tap and check which object it is hitting.

```c#
void Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            //Select Stage
            if (hit.transform.name == "Head")
            {
                //Clicked Head
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the problem here is that most of the events are on the abs part, where is the instetine, liver, kidney, so, can I put 3 colliders on the abs part?

Comment: @Oscar.Aldaz, yes you can.

Comment: How, cause i can´t even move one collider to the head, always, when i create a collider, just stays in the middle and i just can change the dimensiosn but i can´t the position, @ZayedUpal

Comment: Please give me your scene view and the inspector view with the collider selected

Comment: thanks,@ZayedUpal i resolved that, i just need to know from all of my colliders, which one was clicked/touched

Comment: You can put on Debug.Log inside the raycast check to be sure which one it is detecting. It should detect the first one it hits. I guess that's what you need. Please have a look at this link for details on Physics.Raycast: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html